# confusing java: a method calls another method which returns something

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have been working on this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) and the following code has stumped me:

```
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {

    getRequestQueue();
    //getRequestQueue returns an object, but we dont have any variable to receive it.. how is this possible ?

    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}
```

so the problem is that getRequestQueue returns an object, but we dont have any variable to receive it.. how is this possible ?

example: shouldnt it be like this:

```
RequestQueue x = getRequestQueue();
```

therefore, how can we work with what RequestQueue returns, when we did not capture it in a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

`getRequestQueue()`, contrary to its name, is actually a method with side-effects. This is why it makes sense to call that method and discard its return value. The state of the program will have changed after the method returns.

Answer (score 0):

It should if you need to utilize the object returned.

Sometimes, methods returning objects implement some logic that does *something*, which justifies the invocation without assignment.

It looks like the method modifies an instance variable called `mRequestQueue`, by assigning it a value.

Therefore it returns that value, but also impacts on the instance of your class.

Bottom line, syntactically this is not a mistake, although it looks like poor design.

Answer (score 0):

The getter lazy-initializes the member variable `mRequestQueue` of the class, then refers to the member variable directly.

Any reasonable person would change

```
getRequestQueue();
if (mImageLoader == null) {
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
            new LruBitmapCache());
}
```

to

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
if (mImageLoader == null) {
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
            new LruBitmapCache());
}
```

Does the same thing, but definitely more readable, isn't it?